# How can I use map inside an array which has another arrray?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Actually I am using Rapid API for my college project and want to display the flights tickets according the given departure date and return date. The response is something like this  [the response results image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKWuY.png) I just want to display the purchaseLinks array information, basically I want to map both the flights and purchaseLinks array [every purchaseLinks has got 17 keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsfOi.png)
I would mostly wrap all the info in a bootstrap card for good UI

I know this is wrong but I just tried doing this

```
fetch(mainUrl, options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        const res = response.data.flights.purchaseLinks.map(e => e.commerceName);
        console.log(res);
    //console.log(response.data.flights[0].purchaseLinks[0].commerceName)
  })
```

I tried console logging just the first one it was pretty simple to do but just like that I want to do for all the info in the given result json. I am really stuck out here is there any possible way to do this ? If yes please guide your fellow junior
Thank you :)

Comment: An easy way is to write a function that takes `response` as a parameter and knows how to write out the info it contains.  Then call this function instead of `console.log`

Comment: Just saying, JavaScript already has a function named fetch so you might want to use something else

Answer (score 0):

```
const res = response.data.flights.map(f => f.purchaseLinks.map(e => e.commerceName));
```

if you need 2d array and

```
const res = response.data.flights.flatMap(f => f.purchaseLinks).map(e => e.commerceName));
```

for 1d

Answer (score 0):

If `purchaseLinks` array will always contains a single object. In that case you can simply apply the .map method on `flights` array and then access the `purchaseLinks` array object using `zero` index.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const flights = [{
  segemtns: [],
  purchaseLinks: [{
    commerceName: 'Alpha'
  }]
}, {
  segemtns: [],
  purchaseLinks: [{
    commerceName: 'Beta'
  }]
}, {
  segemtns: [],
  purchaseLinks: [{
    commerceName: 'Gamma'
  }]
}, {
  segemtns: [],
  purchaseLinks: [{
    commerceName: 'Abc'
  }]
}, {
  segemtns: [],
  purchaseLinks: [{
    commerceName: 'Xyz'
  }]
}];

const link = flights.map(obj => obj.purchaseLinks[0].commerceName);

console.log(link);
```

If purchaseLinks contains multiple objects, Then you can use two `map` to get all the `commerceName`.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const flights = [{
  segemtns: [],
  purchaseLinks: [{
    commerceName: 'Alpha'
  }, {
    commerceName: 'A1'
  }]
}, {
  segemtns: [],
  purchaseLinks: [{
    commerceName: 'Beta'
  }, {
    commerceName: 'B1'
  }]
}, {
  segemtns: [],
  purchaseLinks: [{
    commerceName: 'Gamma'
  }, {
    commerceName: 'G1'
  }]
}, {
  segemtns: [],
  purchaseLinks: [{
    commerceName: 'Abc'
  }]
}, {
  segemtns: [],
  purchaseLinks: [{
    commerceName: 'Xyz'
  }]
}];

const link = flights.map(obj => {
    return obj.purchaseLinks.map(linkObj => linkObj.commerceName)
});

console.log(link.flat());
```